# Java- Need help setting name of a JMenuItem

Tags: java

```
if (calEvt.getSiSrvOrdNbr() != null) {
        final JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(
                new SisCrossAppJumpAction(system, SisJumpActionTarget.SERVICE_ORDER) {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected Multimap<String, String> getExtraData() {
                        Integer siServiceOrderNumber =        sisServiceOrder.getSiSrvOrdNbr();//calEvt.getSiSrvOrdNbr();
                        Long saCustomerIdNumber = sisServiceOrder.getSaCustIdNbr();
                        Multimap<String, String> extraData = ArrayListMultimap.create();

                        if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(saCustomerIdNumber.toString()) || !StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(
                                siServiceOrderNumber.toString())) {
                            addTarget(extraData);
                            extraData.put("saCustIdNbr", saCustomerIdNumber.toString());
                            extraData.put("siSrvOrdNbr", siServiceOrderNumber.toString());
                        }
                        return extraData; //todo test service order populate info
                    }
                }
        );
        linkMenu.add(menuItem);
    }
```

The snippet above is being used to jump to another application on click of a JMenuItem. Via this method, the name is empty and a blank field is shown in the JMenu. I am looking for a way to set the name of the action here. Normally, I'd use something like

```
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("name of JMenuItem here") {
```

but in this case, I don't think that is possible? Any help is appreciated
(SISCrossAppJumpAction extends AbstractAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the constructor of `SisCrossAppJumpAction`. It needs to call `super("name")` to set the name.

Or you can use `putValue(NAME, "name")` inside of an anonymous code block:

```
... new SisCrossAppJumpAction(...) {
    { putValue(NAME, "name"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private final Action exitAction = new AbstractAction() {

    {
        putValue(NAME, "Exit");
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Exit the application.");
    }
```

You can use an initializer block `{ ... }`.

This construct is useful for miscellaneous things, also as `static { ... }`:

```
static final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
    map.put("word", "vorto");
    ...
}
```